# How to make Tastypie reject unrecognized input data

Tags: django, rest, validation, tastypie

I am currently using [Tastypie](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/toc.html) to provide a programmatic interface to my Django database. On problem that I've run into a couple of times is that when client code uploads data for a field that doesn't exist, Tastypie ignores it. This means that the client code has no idea that some of the data that it tried to upload was ignored. I'd like to tell the client that it tried to upload an unknown field, possible with a status code 406 (not acceptable).

I have two related questions:

- **Is it appropriate for RESTful design to reject this extra data?**
- **If so, is there a tidy way to do this through Tastypie?**

As an example of my concern, consider this toy Tastypie API:

```py
 from tastypie import resources, fields

 class DemoResource(resources.ModelResource):
     name = fields.CharField()
     optional = fields.CharField(blank=True)
```

If client code uploaded the json data: `{name: "new data", optioanl: "this field is misspelled"}`, the misspelled optional field would be ignored. My current plan is to use a Tastypie validator to compare the bundle data against the bundle object, but this seems really non-DRY.

Comment: you can downvote me but, just use the django-rest-framework, this is much better.

Comment: https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#validation rewrite a validation